# SQL Alternate results 2 columns with ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY fid,key ORDER BY fid,key) without repeating the fid for every key

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently working with MS SQL I would like to alternate my sql results by two columns. Something very similar to

```
SELECT  id, fid, key
FROM    TEST
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY fid ORDER BY fid)
```

But using two columns for it. For example, if I have the following info in a table:

### id | fid | key

1  | 1   | KEY1 
2  | 2   | KEY1 
3  | 3   | KEY1 
4  | 1   | KEY2 
5  | 2   | KEY2 
6  | 3   | KEY2 
7  | 1   | KEY3

And i Would like the output to be either 
1  | 1   | KEY1 
5  | 2   | KEY2 
3  | 3   | KEY1 
4  | 1   | KEY2 
2  | 2   | KEY1 
6  | 3   | KEY2 
7  | 1   | KEY3

or

4  | 1   | KEY2 
2  | 2   | KEY1 
6  | 3   | KEY2 
7  | 1   | KEY3 
5  | 2   | KEY2 
3  | 3   | KEY1 
1  | 1   | KEY1

So that the order goes from 1 to n (3 in this case) for the fids but also alternates the k keys (3 in this example) every row

I've tried

```
SELECT  id, fid, key
FROM    TEST
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY fid,key ORDER BY fid,key), fid
```

But that gets me
1  | 1   | KEY1 
4  | 1   | KEY2 
7  | 1   | KEY3 
2  | 2   | KEY1 
5  | 2   | KEY2 
3  | 3   | KEY1 
6  | 3   | KEY2

Which is pretty close to what I need, but It gives me the fid value for every key, when I just need the fid to go 1,2,3 while changing keys every row. Any ideas?

Comment: a very odd OP...

Comment: There are ways to do this but they aren't very elegant. For example, `ORDER BY (DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [key]) - 1) / 2, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [key] ORDER BY fid) + DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [key])) % 2, fid;` Essentially, break them up into pairs, break those pairs up based on odd-odd/even-even or odd-even/even-odd then order by fid. There are other ways you could do this, but the point is to figure out the logic of what you're trying to achieve and then do something based on that. Overall, though, I'd question why you ever need this done in SQL.